# Firefox changed adress bar search engine from Google to Wikipedia after update

Tags: firefox

How do I change it back to Google without having to reset everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the little arrow in the search box, and then choose Google as your search engine.

[image]

If the above doesn't work, try [SearchReset](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/searchreset/)This is a simple Firefox extension that backs up existing values of the home page and keyword search preferences, and then resets them to their default values. It also resets the current search engine to the original default engine, and then uninstalls itself.

also, make sure in `about:config` that:

```
browser.fixup.alternate.enabled should be false
keyword.enabled should be true
keyword.URL should be http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=
```

Comment: Default is Google, even in about:config. But when I enter stuff in the adress bar it searches Wikipedia.

Comment: See the added info in my answer.

Comment: Sorry every new session the settings are lost :(

Comment: @arno See new additions, and let me know if it works.

Comment: browser.fixup.alternate.enablted was "true", keyword.URL doesn't exist. seems to be working now!

Comment: the changes to about:config are not permanent :(

Comment: I tried here, and I do a lot changes in `about:config`, and everything works OK, and is permanent.  Are you getting any new error messages?  Please don't keep accepting, and un-accepting the answer, because it may confuse others with similar problems.

Comment: I never got any error messages. Right now it's working. Considered solved.

Comment: Ok, but let me know if it comes back, or if you get any other issues, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Well it sorta works whenever it wants to... The changes to about:config ARE permanent - sorry - but the problem persists.