# smart keyword usage: How to search IMDB, Wikipedia and more from the address bar

Tags: firefox, gui, browser, search, bookmarks

> Smart keywords are an easy way to search specific websites directly
>   from the Firefox Location bar. Instead of going to the targeted
>   website, finding the search function, and executing the search, you
>   can search the website using Firefox, while you are at any website.

Sounds good.  [Directions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar) are:

> To create a smart keyword:
>
> 1. Visit the page on the target website that has the search field that you would normally use to search the site.
> 2. Right-click on the search field. Select **Add a Keyword for this Search...**.

What does these directions mean?

What or where is the search field?

[image: new way]

It used to be like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/330189/45156):

[image: old way]

I'm can adapt.  Or, maybe not.  Can't figure out this new way.  My system:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 64.0
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~$
```

I'm not seeing the option for http://www.onelook.com/

[image: onelook]

Must be my system or the way I'm using it.

Comment: I like the second way because I can see the icons and I don't have top type anything.

Comment: I know.  But I'd like to at least try these new fangled gadgets these from those whippernsnappers at Firefox.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you're confused about. Your two screenshots (Wikipedia and OneLook) clearly show the "Add a Keyword for this Search..." button.

Comment: Whoops, I must've had "smart" as something I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click in the search bar on the website itself. The <kbd>Add a keyword for this search</kbd> option should then be visible. (I use it for onelook.com, myself.)

You may need to click **in the search input** (where you type), ***not*** on the search button itself (the magnifying glass in your Wikipedia screenshot).

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this as the answer; possibly I have some other problem.  I right clicked in the search box for onelook where I would type a search term.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the second screenshot, you want to [add a search engine](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox), not a keyword.

Comment: Pardon, I'll clarify the question.  I want to use smark keywords

Comment: I crack myself up.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to create a shortcut like I'm used to reading a particular article again and again or need it once in a while. So, I'll create a new **keyword** associated to search for that article to conveniently access it which will eventually get displayed in Bookmarks. For example if I create a smart keyword for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) and assign it keyword "ab" (which I want to search).

[image]

then whenever I enter "ab" in address bar automatically it will show me [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) and try to search ab there.

[image]

To add a search engine, click on 3 horizontal dots and click *Add Search Engine*

[image]

To change search engine while searching, click on [image]

[image]

Also, Firefox has merged search and address bar. To separate it if you prefer it separated, go to *Preferences→Search→Add Search bar in toolbar*.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not seeing the "keyword" option.  I do have "tags" when I add a bookmark.  More digging on my part required.

Comment: @Thufir You're *not* supposed bookmark the page. Instead right-click in the search box in a webpage and select "Add a keyword for this Search..." option (as shown in your first screenshot with Wikipedia). Then you'll see the pop-up as in the first screenshot in this answer. Seems like you're confused between smart keyword and a search engine. This answer is by far the most detailed answer that explains both the notions imo.

Comment: @Thufir I would just add once you added the keyword `xyz` for `somesite.com` then typing "`xyz your search term`" in the addressbar would search for `your search term` in `somesite.com` and show the search results. This is how smart keywords work.